# How should I slice and orchestrate a configurable batch network using Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-batch-tasklet

We would like to migrate the scheduling and sequence control of some Kettle import jobs from a proprietary implementation to a Spring Batch flavour, good practice implementation.

I intend to use Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) server to implement and run a configurable sequence of the existing external import jobs.

The **SCDF console Task editor UI** seems promising to assemble a flow. So one Task wraps one Spring Batch, which in a single step only executes a Tasklet starting and polling the Carte REST API. Does this make sense so far?

Would you suggest a better implementation?

Constraints and Requirements:

- The external Kettle jobs are triggered and polled using Carte REST API. Actually, it's one single Kettle job implementation, called with individual parameters for each entity to be imported.
- There is a configurable, directed graph of import jobs for several entities, some of them being dependent on a correct import of the previous entity type. (e.g. Department, then Employee, then Role assignments...)
- With the upcoming implementation, we would like to get

  - monitoring and controlling (start, abort, pause, resume)
  - restartability
  - easy reconfigurability of the sequence in production (possibly by GUI, or external editor)
  - possibly some reporting and statistics.

As my current understanding, this could be achieved by using Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) server, and some Task / Batch implementation / combination.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but a single Spring Batch job with its hardwired flow seems not very suitable to me. Or is there an easy way to edit and redeploy a Spring Batch with changed flow in production? I couldn't find anything, not even an easy to use editor for the XML representation of a batch.

Comment: related to @MichaelMinella 's post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386991/spring-batch-flow-job-vs-spring-composed-task/44392691#44392691 though I would like to ask for a more concrete implementation advice with this more specific question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe you can achieve your design goals using Spring Cloud Data Flow along with the Spring Cloud Task/Spring Batch.

The flow of multiple Spring Batch Jobs (using the Composed Task) can be managed using Spring Cloud Data Flow as you pointed from the other SO thread.

> The external Kettle jobs are triggered and polled using Carte REST API. Actually, it's one single Kettle job implementation, called with individual parameters for each entity to be imported.
>
> There is a configurable, directed graph of import jobs for several entities, some of them being dependent on a correct import of the previous entity type. (e.g. Department, then Employee, then Role assignments...)

Again, both the above can be managed as a Composed Task (with the composed task consisting of a regular task as well as Spring Batch based applications).

You can manage the parameters passed to each task/batch upon invocation via batch job parameters or task/batch application properties or simply command-line arguments.

> With the upcoming implementation, we would like to get
> monitoring and controlling (start, abort, pause, resume)
> restartability
> easy reconfigurability of the sequence in production (possibly by GUI, or external editor)
> possibly some reporting and statistics.

Spring Cloud Data Flow helps you achieve these goads. You can visit the [Task Developer Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#task-dev-guide) and the [Task Monitoring Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#tasks-monitoring) for more info.

You can also check the [Batch developer guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/) from the site as well.